# How to clone a list of GIT repositories?

Tags: git, git-clone

I have a list of 70+ GIT repo URLs(students). Is there any feature that allows me to clone them all at once?

Would there be the same for synchronizing the repository with the server?

If not, I guess I'd need to write a quick shell script in order to do this.

Comment: shell script is the way to go

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Alright, I'll post the shell script as answer once I'm done.

Comment: I use Checkoutmanager ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/checkoutmanager ), a simple tool for updating a list of repositories.

Comment: Finished the shell script. Will post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Shell scripting.

### Getting the repos

The principal idea to get the repos is

```
while read repo; do
    git clone "$repo"
done < repolist.txt
```

assuming the file "repolist.txt" contains one repo URL per line.

### Updating the repos

This one is trickier.

While it's easy to iterate over the list of repos,
there's the *conceptual* problem with "synchronizing".
Its essense roots in that when you clone the "normal" way — that is, not specifying different funky command-line options modifying the `git clone`'s defaults — all the branches of the source repo end up being created in the form of the so-called "remote branches" in your resulting local repo.
Those remote branches merely track the state of the matching branches in the source repo.  A single branch, designated as the "current" in the source repo, is then taken, and a *local* (that is, yours only) branch is created out of it.  That's why when you clone a repo with 100 branches you end up having only a single local branch (which is "master" in 99.9% cases).

What follows, is that automatic "synchronization" is a moot point here: when you do `git fetch origin` in a "normally" cloned repo, the remote branches get updated with their new contents and are hence almost<sup>1</sup> fully synchronized.
Note that your local branches are not touched at all.
That's because you might have your local work done on them,
and so you have to decide on how do you want to reconcile the updated
state of the remote branches with your local branches, if at all.
This is just the default work model assumed by Git because that's what
needed in most cases.

If, instead, you don't intend to do any work on the branches of those repos,
and they are for inspection only, the easiest approach is to
make Git have no remote branches at all.

To do this, you clone using several explicit steps:

1. Initialize an empty repository:

   ```
   git init <dirname>
   ```
2. Configure a remote there:

   ```
   git remote add --mirror=fetch origin <url>
   ```

   The `--mirror=fetch` tells Git to setup the mapping of what to fetch
   to what to update with the fetched data in a way which forcefully
   overwrites all local stuff with the remote stuff.
3. Fetch all the data — overwriting everything local:

   ```
   git fetch -u origin
   ```

   The `-u` (or `--update-head-ok`) permits Git to overwrite the branch
   pointed to by the `HEAD` reference.  This pulls the rug from the feet
   of the index and the work tree but we'll compensate for that on the next step.
4. Force-update the index and the work tree using the new data:

   ```
   git reset --hard HEAD
   ```

   This makes Git overwrite the index and the work tree with the up-to-date state of the branch pointed at by `HEAD` — typically "master" but should you check another branch out (see below) it will
   obviously use that one.

Then, to update the data next time you do:

```
git fetch -u origin
git reset --hard HEAD
```

and then study what's in the work tree.

If you need to view another branch, the usual

```
git branch -a
```

…observe the list and pick a branch, then

```
git checkout <that_branch>
```

will work.

In essense, all this dance with explicit repo initialization and adding of a remote in a special way is needed because the `--mirror` option
of `git clone` implies creating a bare repository, and we supposedly want
a normal one (I think).

To update all the repos located in a directory, do

```
find "$root_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print \
    | while read repo; do \
        cd "$repo" && \
        git fetch -u origin && \
        git reset --hard HEAD \
      done
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The branches deleted in the remote repo are not deleted locally. To do that, you have to run `git remote prune origin`.

Comment: git clone $repo     <------ without quotes

Comment: @Anthony Piñero, care to elaborate? The shell would strip them while substituting the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "super project" that includes all mentioned Git repos as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) (also see the [Git SCM book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)), or use a tool like [repo](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html#installing-repo) that uses a manifest to manage all repositories.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo $line
    git clone https://your-git-repo-link/"$line".git
done < cat.txt
```

cat.txt contains a list of repo names.

customer-service

device-swap

platform-downtime

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I easily cloned a list of repos using Python. This code works cross-platform, but isn't idiot-proof. I advise adding some try-catches.
git_sources.list is obviously your repo list, delimited by newlines.
...

```
    # filename: clone.py
    # purpose: attempts to git clone repos from a list file
    # beware, there are no try-catches in this script
    # run with: python3 clone.py
    import os

    cmdstr = ""
    sources_path = "git_sources.list"

    # maybe surround all this with a try-catch if you want
    with open(sources_path, "r") as sources_file:
        for line in sources_file:
            print("cloning from:")
            print(line)
            cmdstr= "git clone " + line
            os.system(cmdstr)
```